# How could I make a "banishing arrow"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using command blocks in 1.16, how would I make an arrow, that when it hits someone, it /execute in the_end run tp   them to the Nether or end?

Comment: `/warp` isn't a command in the base game, did you mean `/tp`?

Comment: This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14mBKL53Fy0